# Workflow Manager service running under system account

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016, workflow-manager, system-account

I want to know what is the correct sentence from one of the following. It is about running workflow manager service and publishing SharePoint 2013 workflows from SPD. On my farm, I have published workflows but they are not running when I create an item in the list (workflow is set to run on item creation)

Could it be due to system account so I want to clear this thing up.

1. Workflow Manager service should not run under system account but system account can publish workflows in SPD
2. Workflow Manager service can run under system account but system account should not publish workflows in SPD
3. Workflow Manager service should not run under system account and neither system account should publish workflows

Answer (score 0):

If we add the workflow actions in App step, we can use system account to publish and start the workflow.

If not, the workflow will not function properly and start automatically when the item created by system account.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this part "If we add the workflow actions in App step". I am adding workflow steps normally in SPD.